If statement to check if an array is not in another array
I am currently doing an advent of coding problem link, and my solution involves checking if an array contains another array. however, the if statement doesn't work or something else is messing my code up.
string = " *really long thing, i deleted it* "
# example string = "v>"
location = [0,0]
been_to = [[0,0]]
string = list(string)

for i in string:
    if i == "v":
        #down
        location[1] -= 1
    elif i == "^":
        #up
        location[1] += 1
    elif i == ">":
        #right
        location[0] -= 1
    elif i == "<":
        #left
        location[0] += 1
    if location in been_to == False:
        been_to.append(location)
    #print(location)
print(been_to)


I have tried swapping the variables, moving a not or == false around, and generally trying anything that comes to mind. I still have no clue.

if location not in been_to:

Your check fails because been_to == False is false. What you have is a chained comparison. You virtually never use == False or == True in Python.

Why not use match case statement instead of if/else nested?
